# Facebook says valid URL is not a valid URL

Tags: facebook, url, url-validation

Trying to add the App Domain to a new app.

Thing is the domain is http://the.me

Facebook doesn't consider this to be a valid URL.

Any workaround?

Answer (score 3):

Are you including `http://` in there? It shouldn't have that. Just use `the.me` as your domain. I just tried it and it worked for me.

See example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vil7.jpg

Comment: Tried that Calvin, getting this error message: "Error
You have specified an App Domain but have not specified a Site URL or a Mobile Web URL
the.me must be derived from your Site URL or your Mobile Web URL."

Comment: But why would it work with you? The fourth field under Settings - Basic Info - App Domain?

Comment: Yes -- that's the one. Are you reading the error message? It says you also need to specify a site URL. Use `the.me` for App Domain, and use `http://the.me` for the website url. See this: http://imgur.com/g8sjE

Comment: @CalvinL I have also been struggling with the same issue. But now fixed it. Thanks a lot Calvin.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using http://www.the.me

adding the www might work with FB

Comment: Tried that, doesn't work. Am trying to link Wordpress to Facebook - so this not-valid URL is a major stumbling block. Any alternative?